# How can I check if a multi-file copy was successful?

Tags: windows-7, backup

Using Windows 7 Ultimate. I made almost 1TB backup into my new 2TR RAID-1 setup. I left it running for the night and now I'm not sure if the copy was successful. How could I verify that the source and the destination files are the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can try '[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php)', 
but if you want to make sure it is done properly you can try to use utilities like '[teracopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php)'.

Comment: Teracopy has an option to verify that a copy was successful by calculating checksums. Since you've already done the copy, you would need to use the "test files" option instead.

Answer (score 0):

you calculate a checksum for each file and compare them, for example with "[FileVerifier++](http://www.programmingunlimited.net/siteexec/content.cgi?page=fv)"